# Will there be a movie based on "American Gods" by Neil Gaiman?

Tags: movie, neil-gaiman, american-gods

I loved reading excerpts out of "[American Gods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Gods)" by Neil Gaiman and I also saw that it was received very well by receiving a bunch of awards, especially the [Hugo](http://www.thehugoawards.org/) and the [Nebula](http://www.sfwa.org/nebula-weekend/), so I was wondering if someone knows if there are plans for making a movie based on this book.

Comment: American Gods would be ruined by trying to shoehorn it into a 90 or 120 minute movie. It could possibly be serialised as HBO are doing for GRRMs Song of Ice and fire, but a Movie? Not in my humble opinion.

Comment: I'm going to remove the hugo and nebula tags, because they are only tangentially related to the topic.  I've read that many feel that every tag has to be able to define the question. If you disagree feel free to voice your objections in chat.

Comment: [I thought speculations were off-topic?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/233/how-do-we-deal-with-questions-about-rumors-and-release-dates/234#234)

Comment: @Ivo: Yes, but if you can document your answer (as benstraw did), it's no longer speculation.

Comment: But you don't know this beforehand, surely we're not going to wait for a definitive answer before deciding what to do with it @Gilles?

Comment: Well, looking at how the events unfold in this particular case. Not yet. Who knows if it actually gets done.... Here my hopes going up again :)

Comment: [inkista's answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/94160/70236) turned out to be correct. There is even [a trailer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/94160/70236) now

Comment: Update - Episode 1 was brilliant!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, there is currently no publicized plan to make a movie of this novel. Gaiman was quoted as saying:

> I'm currently keeping them off the market, which my agent may find a little frustrating.

[http://www.the-trades.com/ article](http://www.the-trades.com/article.php?id=1626)

Albeit this quote is from 2002, but so far he seems to be sticking to his word, I follow his work pretty closely and have not seen anything to seems to change this.

Comment: This is correct (kinda). They made it into a mini-series rather than a movie.

Answer (score 19):

[HBO Adapting Neil Gaiman’s AMERICAN GODS](http://www.obsessedwithfilm.com/tv-news/hbo-adapting-neil-gaimans-american-gods.php)  April 15, 2011 9:57 am

Just days before HBO unveils their adaptation of George RR Martin’s novel Game of Thrones on Sunday which they translated into an epic-sized production, comes news from Deadline that attention has turned to Neil Gaiman’s American Gods.

Author Neil Gaiman answered some questions on Reddit in 2013, one of which was related to American Gods. According to Gaiman, a series based on the book is still in the works, but it’s no longer being developed at HBO. Continue below to read his quote.

[When asked the question](http://www.geeksofdoom.com/2013/11/20/neil-gaiman-says-american-gods-longer-development-hbo) *“I always hear things about an American Gods HBO Series, pilots and greenlights and all sorts of things. Whats the truth?”* Gaiman answered:

*“There is an American Gods TV series in the works. It’s no longer with HBO. The moment that things are ready to be announced I am sure they will be, either legitimately or via a leak in a big Hollywood Agency mailroom.”*

**Update**

Now American Gods has found a new home. It’s been announced that FreemantleMedia has acquired the rights to the project, though it’s not yet known what channel you can expect to see the show on yet.

*“A few people have asked for more background on this: HBO had an option on American Gods for several years. It went through three different pilot scripts. HBO has a limited number of slots and, after a while, passed it to Cinemax, who are in the HBO family, who decided eventually they didn’t want to do it, and the option expired, which unfortunately meant we couldn’t work with Tom Hanks’ production company Playtone any longer, as they are exclusive to HBO. However, Stefanie Berk, who had been one of the brightest stars at Playtone, had recently moved to Freemantle, and was as determined as she had been when she was at Playtone to bring American Gods to the screen. And I was impressed by her determination.”*

[“There is an American Gods TV series in the works,” Gaiman wrote in the AMA. “It’s no longer with HBO.](http://spinoff.comicbookresources.com/2014/02/03/fremantlemedia-acquires-tv-rights-to-neil-gaimans-american-gods/)

[Extra Information from Neil's blog](http://journal.neilgaiman.com/2014/02/american-gods-tv-series-news-and-more.html)

Comment: Good news! With Gaiman involved in the writing, they won't destroy it.

Comment: They did quite a poor job with 'neverwhere' despite his involvement.

Comment: Generally Gaiman's works adapts well to screen. Indeed, some of his novels started out as screenplays that he couldn't sell to studios. But you should be warned that Gaiman is one of those authors who don't mind if adaptations differ in detail from the book. So judge the series for what it is instead of simply a re-telling of the book.

Answer (score 7):

While it wasn't made as a movie, and the HBO/Playtone series fell through, it **is** [a television series on the Starz network](https://www.starz.com/play/31216?isseries=true), and produced by Freemantle. The showrunners for the first season were Bryan Fuller *(Hannibal, Pushing Daisies, Wonderfalls)* and Michael Green *(Kings)*. Neil Gaiman is an executive producer.

The first season premiered on April 30, 2017, 9pm EST and consisted of eight one-hour episodes. * David Slade *(Hannibal)* directed the first three episodes.  See also [the IMDb listing for the series](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1898069/combined). Principal cast included Ricky Whittle as Shadow Moon, Emily Browning as Laura Moon, and Ian McShane as Mr. Wednesday, and Gillian Anderson as Media.

The second series of *American Gods* airs on Starz on March 10, 2019 8pm EST, and is eight episodes. However, [Fuller and Green are no longer the showrunners](https://www.hollywoodreporter.com/live-feed/american-gods-sidelines-new-showrunner-delays-frustrations-1140946), nor is their replacement, Jesse Alexander. This has also apparently led to Gillian Anderson leaving the cast; they have created a new character, New Media (played by Kahyun Kim), to take the place of Media.  Neil Gaiman is still involved, but is busy showrunning *Good Omens* for Amazon Prime.

Comment: There's now [a trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oyoXURn9oK0) you might want to add.

Comment: @Gallifreyan Those tend to be temporary links. Hence my not linking to the [Comic-con panel youtube video](https://youtu.be/Id5CIAXQ9Ug), either. :-)

Comment: The IMDB links may be better then